# Develop Provider Hosted-App in SharePoint 2016 Environment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, provider-hosted-app

I required to develop Provider Hosted-App for access .Net Web Application in SharePoint 2016 environment.

Required link for any useful blog or direction of the process.

Thanks in advance for help and suggestion.

Comment: were you unable to find the documentation? Is there something specific you're having difficulty with?

Comment: Is Provider Hosted-App supports in SharePoint 2016?

Comment: yes, provider hosted apps are supported. Though, with the right service pack, SPFx is also supported on 2016, so you may want to look into that as well.

Comment: Is SPFx supports the Web API? As per requirement, we developed .net application with reference of Web API that we have to apply to SharePoint 2016 environment. Kindly share your thoughts here.

Comment: Can you call web api from spfx? yes.

Comment: I created Provide-Hosted App using Visual Studio but can't deploy the solution. Getting error : "The local SharePoint server is not available. Check that the server is running and connected to the SharePoint farm." Kindly share service account required for App configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your environment as official document below.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-an-environment-for-apps-for-sharepoint

Then, you could develop SharePoint provider-hosted add-in by Visual Studio(Auto Hosted deprecated).

https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-approach-to-create-a-provider-hosted-application-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Is Provider-Hosted App supports .net Web API which supports to SharePoint 2016 environment?

Comment: Check this thread https://ypcode.wordpress.com/2017/12/29/sharepoint-add-in-custom-web-api-and-spfx/

Comment: I created Provide-Hosted App using Visual Studio but can't deploy the solution. Getting error : "The local SharePoint server is not available. Check that the server is running and connected to the SharePoint farm." Kindly share diff service account required for App configuration.